# Where does Exchange 2016 write error 500 details to?

Tags: windows, exchange, windows-server-2016, exchange-2016

Getting HTTP error 500 [after a successful login to Exchange Administrative Center](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8cf6886f-a96f-44f1-88ee-bd3a42349fa9/owa-brings-up-logon-screen-but-after-login-gives-http-500-internal-server-error?forum=exchangesvrclients), I'm cluess where OWA writes HTTP 500 errors to.

I can neither see any relevant entries in the Windows Event Log, nor find any log files beside the standard IIS logs that contain no further details.

Being an ASP.NET application, I would have expected to see some log files with detailed stack trace and exception/error messages for the HTTP error 500.

**My question:**

Are there any log files that contain details about an HTTP error 500 in OWA/Exchange Administrative Center?

Comment: I didn't actually find out, and simply reinstalled Exchange to fix it. Still, the next time, I would probably go this way: 1.) Modify the web.config for `customErrors="Off"` 2.) Remove the error 500 handler entry from web.config, too 3.) Hope that now the error 500 is being sent in details to my client if I call it locally.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you could refer to the following KB( which also applies in Exchange 2016). Follow the steps in the article.
[Exchange 2013 Unable to access ECP Encounter “500 Unexpected Error”](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31044.exchange-2013-unable-to-access-ecp-encounter-500-unexpected-error.aspx)

Also,  what about checking the IIS log in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1

Comment: Thank you. I am not looking for IIS log file location, since I do know them and since they do not contain any application specific error details.

Comment: I want to confirm that whether you can’t find any relative error logs in the event viewer on your mailbox server actually?

This link: The HTTP status code in IIS 7 and later versions 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0
records different status code and their meanings, check whether it helps?